# Error with sapply in R

Tags: r, sapply

I'm generating 100 random numbers from Dirichlet distribution, and then I need to use the output to generate from Gamma distribution. Here is the code:

```
a <- rdirichlet(100, c(1,1,1))
b <- c(3,3,3)

sapply(a, function(x) {rgamma(100, shape=2, rate =(b%*%a)) })
```

Note here that the rate for gamma distribution is the dot product of vectors b and a (which is the output from Dirichlet).

I'm getting this error message:

```
Error in b %*% a : non-conformable arguments
```

Comment: `sapply` applies a function to each element of a. You're not using it correectly.

Comment: @ Roman Luštrik: I believe the problem is when multiplying b%*%a. Do you know how to get the dot product here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want. My library has at least four different packages with `rdirichlet` functions.):

```
library(MCMCpack)
apply(a,  1, function(x) {rgamma(100, shape=2, rate =(b %*% x)) })
```

When vectors are passed to %*% then need to be the same length and sapply was  passing single elements rather than length-3 rows. (You also didn't have "x" in the expression.)

```
c(3,3,3) %*% 1
#Error in c(3, 3, 3) %*% 1 : non-conformable arguments

 str(a %*% b) 
 # vectors can be assumed to be column matrices in the second position
 num [1:100, 1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

OR:

```
> str(b %*% t(a))
# .... or assumed to be row matrices in the first position.
 num [1, 1:100] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

Comment: when I run this code, the output is 100x100 matrix, but I believe it should be 100x1.

Comment: Why? You _are_ asking for 100 random gamma draws with each new row from "a".

Comment: Yes. I want the result of this (b%*%a) to be a single number, and therefore, when I generate from gamma, I'll get 100 numbers.

Comment: And that _is_ what you are getting. 100 (a%*%x's) x 100 (rgamma-calls).

Comment: If yo just want an 100 x 1 matrix then do not generate 100 rgammas with each iteration.

Comment: ok, cool! One more thing I'm still not sure about: when i run this code, i get 100 numbers: 
a <- rdirichlet(100, c(1,1,1))
b <- c(3,3,3)


apply(a,1,function(x) {rgamma(1, shape=2, rate =(b %*% x)) }) ... however, if i want to see the output of b %*% x, then i'm getting an error message: (Error in b %*% x : non-conformable arguments). Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: `apply(a,  1, function(x) b %*% x )`  Or `b %*% t(a)`

Comment: Let's consider this example: a <- rdirichlet(100, c(1,1,1))
b <- c(3,3,3) ... Here i'm expecting to get 1x100.. but not sure about the output of a%*%b

Comment: column count of first argument must equal rows of second argument: `a %*% b`